# Programa buscador de peliculas

Tags: javascript, ordenar

Estoy realizando una actividad para un curso de *Fullstack*, que consta de una lista de películas en JSON y pasar argumentos por la terminal a la función a través de *node*, como:

- `--sort title`, que ordena el listado de películas por título
- `--buscar aa` (busca películas que en su título tengan 2 a
- `--tag accion`, me tendría que devolver las películas con tag de acción

Esta es la función para interpretar los argumentos que recibo a través de `process.argv`. Previamente, en index, le saco los dos primeros miembros con slice.

```
exports.parsearArgumentos = (argv) => {
  const respuesta = {};
  argv.forEach(function(item, ind) {
    // También me indica el índice
    const valorObjeto = 0;
    if (item.startsWith("--")) {
      const nombreSinGuiones = item.slice(2);
      const valorObjeto = item.ind;
      respuesta[nombreSinGuiones] = argv[ind + 1];
    }
  });
  return respuesta;
};
```

Después, no sé cómo seguir, me estoy volviendo loco un poco más. No puedo sacarle la lógica. Esta es la función para ordenar:

```
exports.Ordenar = (argv) => {
  const peliculas = getPeliculas();
  if (argv.sort == "title") {
    return peliculas.sort(function (a,b){
        if ( a.title < b.title )
        return -1;
      if ( a.title > b.title )
        return 1;
      return 0;
    })
  } else if (argv.sort == "rating") {
    return peliculas.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating);
  }
};
```

A su vez, tendría que ser capaz de hacer esto:

- `--sort title --buscar a`, ordenar por título todas aquellas películas que tengan una A en su título, es decir, poder combinar estas funciones.

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a lo que expusiste en la pregunta, los parámetros son recibidos por pares, es decir `--parametro1 parametro2 --parametro parametro4`, donde el primero especifica una acción y el segundo el valor correspondiente.

### ¿Qué debes hacer?

1. Declara variables para saber qué acciones se deben ejecutar: ordenar, buscar en título o filtrar por etiqueta
2. Recorre los argumentos recibidos para buscar pares de `--acción valor`
3. En cada iteración del ciclo, analiza la acción y actualiza la variable correspondiente
4. Al final del ciclo, analiza cada variable para ejecutar las acciones, comenzando por los filtros y dejando el orden hasta el final

```
exports.parsearArgumentos = (argv) => {
  // ¿Se debe filtrar por etiqueta?
  let tag = '';
  // ¿Buscar un valor específico?
  let search = '';
  // ¿Se deben ordenar los resultados?
  let sort = '';

  // Recorre la lista de argumentos, buscando pares, comenzando en cero
  let index = 0;
  while(index < argv.length) {
      // Si es acción, debe comenzar con --
      let action, value;
      if(argv[index].startsWith('--')) {
          action = argv[index].slice(2);
          // ¿Se proporcionó parámetro para la acción?, no debe comenzar con "--"
          value = (argv[index + 1] && !argv[index + 1].startsWith('--')) ? argv[index + 1] : '';
          // Analizar la acción a realizar
          if(action == 'sort') {
              // Establecer orden, si no se proporcionó, será un valor por defecto
              sort = value || 'titulo';
              // Deberías validar que la propiedad es válida, por ejemplo:
              if(!['titulo', 'rating', 'tag'].includes(sort)) {
                  // Propiedad inválida, poner valor por defecto
                  sort = 'titulo';
              }
          } else if(action == 'buscar') {
              search = value;
          } else if(action == 'tag') {
              tag = value;
          }
      }
      // Incrementar índice en 2 si se proporcionó "--acción valor" o en 1 si no
      index += (action && value) ? 2 : 1;
  }
  return {
      tag: tag,
      search: search,
      sort: sort
  };
}
export.ejecutar(argv) {
  // Obtener todas las películas
  peliculas = getPeliculas();

  // Verificar cada valor para filtrar u ordenar
  if(argv.tag) {
      // Filtrar por etiqueta
      peliculas = peliculas.filter(pelicula => pelicula.tag.toLowerCase() == argv.tag.toLowerCase());
  }
  if(argv.search) {
      // Buscar por término
      peliculas = peliculas.filter(pelicula => pelicula.title.toLowerCase().includes(argv.search.toLowerCase));
  }
  if(argv.sort) {
      // Ordenar, sabiendo que sort contiene la propiedad para determinar el orden
      peliculas.sort((a, b) => a[argv.sort].localeCompare(b[argv.sort]));
  }
  return peliculas;
};
```

**Importante:** No copies y pegues este código, lo más seguro es que contenga errores, porque no tengo la posibilidad de probarlo. Lee los comentarios, ahí explico qué se hace en cada instrucción; trata de entender la lógica y, solo entonces, adáptala para aplicarla en tu proyecto.

No dudes en usar la sección de comentarios debajo de la respuesta para preguntar si no entendiste algo o no quedó claro.

Entre algunas mejoras, puedes crear métodos para ejecutar cada acción, por ejemplo:

```
export.porTag(peliculas, tag) {
    return peliculas.filter(pelicula => pelicula.tag.toLowerCase() == tag.toLowerCase())
}
```